# Specify database schema in MapServer mapfile

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I have my mapfile. I am able to connect to my PostGIS database when my table is under the public schema.

Here is my database structure.

Database

```
Ingham
\__Schemas (3)
    \__2016
        \__Parcels
        \__Parcel Dimensions
    \__2017
        \__Parcels
        \__Parcel Dimensions
    \__public
        \__Parcels
```

The Parcels table under the public schema is a copy from 2016. I can connect to it from my mapfile this way.

```
CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
CONNECTION 'host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dbname=Ingham user=ingham_mapserver'
DATA 'wkb_geometry from Parcels'
```

This works great. When I try to specify a schema, like I would in a postgresql query,

```
CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
CONNECTION 'host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dbname=Ingham user=ingham_mapserver'
DATA 'wkb_geometry from "2017"."Parcels"'
```

Has anyone been able to specify a database schema in the mapfile for MapServer?

Comment: Which version of Mapserver are you using?

Comment: Current: v7.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapServer tries to parse the SQL fragment.

When doing anything funny, better move it into a subquery, which will be given to the database as is:

```
DATA 'wkb_geometry from (select wkb_geometry from "2017"."Parcels") as subquery'
```

Comment: This worked for me :) It's funny though, I swear that I tried this a million times yesterday as it says in the documentation `https://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html` that the subqueries get ran on the database server. Anyways, thank you!